# List is not empty but the poll method returns null

Tags: java, tree, queue

My method should compute the depth of nodes in the set `nodes`, but for some trees an `NullPointerException` is invoked, which occurs because `queue.poll()` returns null. In the description of the method it is said, that `queue.poll()` returns null if and only if the queue is empty. This condition is checked in the while loop, so my question is, why this error can occur and how to fix it.

```
private Map<Tree, Integer> determineDepth(Tree root, Set<Tree> nodes) {
    Map<Tree, Integer> depthMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Tree, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedList<Tree> queue = new LinkedList<Tree>();

    depthMap.put(root, 0);
    visited.put(root, true);
    queue.add(root);
    Tree node;
    while (queue.size() != 0) {
        node = queue.poll();
        int depth = depthMap.get(node);
        for (Tree child : node.children()) {
            depthMap.put(child, depth + 1);
            visited.putIfAbsent(child, false);
            if (!visited.get(child)) {
                visited.put(child, true);
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
    return depthMap;
}
```

Comment: I would make `visited` a `Set` and use `if (visited.add(child))`

Comment: You haven't posted the stack trace of the exception, so we can't confirm if your diagnostic is correct. But LinkedList.poll() can return also null if the first element of the list is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `null` to a LinkedList it will be retained. e.g.

```
List l = new LinkedList();
l.add(null);
assert l.size() > 0;
Object o = l.poll(); // == null
```

Comment: I iterate through the children, so no null element may be inserted. So this problem could only occur if the root is null, right?

Comment: @S.Werner I would step through the code in your debugger to confirm this.